# making a config file editable in the staging\prod environment

Tags: angular, configuration, ng-build

I'm trying to figure out how to make a configurable config file in angular, enable me to change its variables values after build to staging or prod.
I created an application.config.ts in the assets folder, knowing that the assets folder is not being minified and copied as is.
There is a component in the app that reads that variable value straight from the config file.
After building the app in staging or prod configuration, when I change one of the variables value in that file (stop IIS, change it and restart the IIS)- it is not changed in the application component.
What should I do in order to make it editable in the staging\prod env. ?

Comment: Couldn't you just use different builds based on different configs in the _angular.json_?

Comment: Load it on app start as an external file (like calling API - using http request) to get its fresh content

Comment: @DonJuwe - What do you mean ? I'm using a different builds - but still - I would like to change the variables after deploying, no matter to what environment - doing a config change without the need to re-deploy\build

Comment: @Benny - this is a solution, but I thought of a simpler solution using some kind of static file

Comment: @GuyE IMHO this is a simple and true data-driven configuration. Configuration should not be compiled. Only default configuration (fallback)